# Removing an element from text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I want to remove the dot above the "i" in Illustrator but still keeping the text as an editable vector object, is this possible?

Comment: expand and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your text and select *Create Outlines*. This turns your type in to "an editable vector object" which you can select with any of the selection tools and delete the dot above the "i".

I suspect what you meant though was keeping your text as live editable type. In which case, no you can't do that. Theres no way to edit the path data of a font in Illustrator whilst keeping it as editable type. You could cheat and hide the dot above the "i" by using a clipping mask, you would need to adjust the mask every time you edit your type though.

Another thing to keep in mind... [There is a dotless i character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131/index.htm). Check to see if your font has that character. If so, problem solved.